# Error al crear proyecto Hibernate en NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, hibernate

Estoy tratando de crear un proyecto web con Hibernate, pero no es posible crear dicho proyecto porque me da este error:

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2 or one of its 
dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:3.1.2: Could not transfer 
artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:pom:3.1.2 from/to 
central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven- 
archetype-plugin/3.1.2/maven-archetype-plugin-3.1.2.pom: Received fatal 
alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]
```

Cabe aclarar lo siguiente:

Estoy usando la versión 12.4 de Apache NetBeans
Cuando voy a crear el proyecto, elijo el servidor GlassFish Server y la versión 8 de Java EE.

Comment: Si escribes en la consola `java -version` ¿qué te muestra?

Comment: Me aparece "java version 15.0.2 2021-01-19"

Comment: puede mostrar el archivo POM del proyecto y el archivo settings.xml de la carpeta .m2

Comment: @Isaac es imposible eso porque ni siquiera me deja crear el proyecto